# Is there any way to check if an element has jquery select2 already applied to it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I want to apply [select2](http://select2.github.io/select2/) to a bunch of jquery elements on the page that all have the same class name but it looks like if i call select2() on an element that already has had a select2() called on it then it blows up.  here is my code

```
 $('.MyDropdowns').each(function (i, obj) {
    $(obj).select2({ width: "455px" });
});
```

so I want something like:

```
 $('.MyDripdowns').each(function (i, obj) {
    if (!$(obj).HasSelect2Initiatized)
    {
        $(obj).select2({ width: "455px" });
    }
});
```

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: Well it looks like it hides the element it's called on, so you could try `if($(obj).is(":visible"))`

Comment: that doesn't seem very fool proof as what if the element is hidden for other reasons?

Comment: Why would you call `select2()` twice?

Comment: @leora Yea, scratch that idea - never used that plugin before, shame their plugin doesn't do what other plugins do and use an 'instance' option. sMr's answer below looks like the way to go

Answer (score 104, accepted):

you can check if the element has `select2` attribute

```
$('.MyDripdowns').each(function (i, obj) {
    if (!$(obj).data('select2'))
    {
        $(obj).select2({ width: "455px" });
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

As @Fr0zenFyr said in his comment for v4.0 you can use :

`if (!$(obj).hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible"))`

Comment: This is still multiplying my selects after postbacks :/

Comment: what do you mean by postbacks?

Comment: Server side processes, especially partial ones with UpdatePanel.

Comment: at least for v4.0, `if (!$(obj).hasClass(select2-hidden-accessible))` test should work. I don't think it works with `data` attribute anymore.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr 's modification worked for me. Just remember hasClass accepts a string as the class name.

Comment: Now it is in the official documentation https://select2.org/programmatic-control/methods#checking-if-the-plugin-is-initialized

Comment: The `data()` check should work if you use `data('select2-id')`.

Answer (score 3):

Working solution:

```
$('.MyDripdowns:not([class^="select2"])').each(function (i, obj) {
    $(obj).select2({width: "455px"});
})
```

Links:

1. [^= attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)
2. [:not selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Above answer is almost correct.  
But it creates problem when we are adding elements dynamically on same page and applying select 2 to newly created element. 
 At that times selector has to be specified using not only class but also with input type. PFB reference code.

```
$('inputp[type="text"].MyDripdowns').each(curr_idx, curr_elem){
    //Check if select 2 is already applied or not
    if($(curr_elem).hasClass('.select2-offscreen')){
      //Select 2 is already applied to this element
    }
    else{
       //Apply Select 2 to this element 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
curSelect.on( 'change', function() {
    curLength = curSelect.select2( 'data' ).length;
    if ( curLength ... ) {
        ...
    }
} );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.