# Maximum call stack size exceeded when using select2 on appended select fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm appending a div that contains a select input, but when I try to initialize select2 on it I get this error and my page doesn't respond until I force quite it.

```
$('.page-content').on('DOMNodeInserted', '.material-container', function () {
    var selectField = $(this).find(".select-material");
    selectField.select2();
});
```

Here is the console error.

```
jquery.js?27d9:5946 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
at HTMLSelectElement.eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://crm.dev:3000/js/vendor.js:71:1), <anonymous>:5946:21)
at domManip (eval at <anonymous> (http://crm.dev:3000/js/vendor.js:71:1), <anonymous>:5759:14)
at jQuery.fn.init.after (eval at <anonymous> (http://crm.dev:3000/js/vendor.js:71:1), <anonymous>:5944:10)
at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.(anonymous function) [as insertAfter] (eval at <anonymous> (http://crm.dev:3000/js/vendor.js:71:1), <anonymous>:6052:37)
at Select2._placeContainer (eval at <anonymous> (http://crm.dev:3000/js/vendor.js:163:1), <anonymous>:5137:16)
at new Select2 (eval at <anonymous> (http://crm.dev:3000/js/vendor.js:163:1), <anonymous>:5063:10)
at HTMLSelectElement.eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://crm.dev:3000/js/vendor.js:163:1), <anonymous>:5667:26)
at Function.each (eval at <anonymous> (http://crm.dev:3000/js/vendor.js:71:1), <anonymous>:368:19)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (eval at <anonymous> (http://crm.dev:3000/js/vendor.js:71:1), <anonymous>:157:17)
at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.select2 (eval at <anonymous> (http://crm.dev:3000/js/vendor.js:163:1), <anonymous>:5664:14)
at HTMLDivElement.eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://crm.dev:3000/js/app.js:149:1), <anonymous>:51:17)
```

Comment: Would it be helpful if you told us what the `.select2()` method's code looks like?

Comment: select2 is a library for selecting fields. All I do is include it in my app and use it. When I use it on static fields it works just fine.

Comment: When you init a select2 instance, ton of things are added to the DOM, DOMNodeInserted event gets fired then you have an infinite loop.

Comment: What is the purpose of the code? as in what are you trying to achieve ? and why do you perform it on `DOMNodeInserted` ?

Comment: I'm allowing the user to append select fields. I'm using plain JS to append it, but jQuery to initialize the select2, because the append happens inside the php file so it will render properly the variables that I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you init a select2 instance, ton of things are added to the DOM, DOMNodeInserted event gets fired then you have a infinite loop.

I have 2 ways to workaround this (of course there are more):

- Check if select2 is already initialized

  [Is there any way to check if an element has jquery select2 already applied to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854022/is-there-any-way-to-check-if-an-element-has-jquery-select2-already-applied-to-it)
- Use jQuery one() instead of on()
  http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Another idea is to buffer the event doing something like this: `var _my_buffer = null; $("#foo").on("bar", function() { if (!_my_buffer) { _my_buffer = setTimeout(function() { doStuff(); _my_buffer = null; }, 100); }});`