# How to show a class once select2 has loaded

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to change a class visibility state to visible once select2 has loaded.

I have been able to hide the class, but the second part of my code doesn't seem to work yet.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.searchandfilter li').css({ 'visibility': 'hidden' })
});

$.when(
    $("select[class*='select2']").select2({
        allowClear: true
    })).done(function () {
        $('.searchandfilter li').css({ 'visibility': 'visible' })
    });
```

Comment: You can not use when/done on just anything, it must be a “Thenable object” - and I rather doubt select2 actually is one. But the creation of such an element should happen almost instantly anyways, so is it not enough if you simply initialize your select2, and then make the other elements visible directly on the next line …?

Comment: Thanks Cristiano for your response..... I have an issue with the IOS select menu showing for a split second,,,, which is why I am trying to wait for select2 to load before showing it....... Would you recommend a different way?

Answer (score 0):

You should not initalise select2 (`$().select2()`) unless you know that the DOM of the page is ready - ie. it should be inside the `ready(function($){...})` block you've got there.

You are using the `$.when()` block incorrectly. These are used for promises which you are not using here. The `done` portion will not fire at all. You should remove this.

Anyway, unless it's doing some fancy callbacks, the `$().select2()` function should initialise select2 immediately, allowing you to hide the .searchandfilter elements immediately after the line to initalise select2.

If that still doesnt work, as a very last resort, I'd put your hiding logic in a `setTimeout()` block and check that select2 is initialised using this: [Is there any way to check if an element has jquery select2 already applied to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854022/is-there-any-way-to-check-if-an-element-has-jquery-select2-already-applied-to-it/29854133#29854133)

Make sure you've read the jQuery and select2 documentation to get familiar with both.

Comment: Thanks Mikepote, I checked out the link and came up with an idea based on the answer, but Amine KOUIS's answer below seems to have worked.... Unfortunately this hasn't fixed my issue of the IOS select menu showing for a split second,,, I should have included that from the start...

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)** and **[hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)** to handle the visibility of your list `<li>` like the code below does:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select2").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".searchandfilter li").show();
            } else{
                $(".searchandfilter li").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select2">
       <option>Choose Text</option>
       <option value="text1">Text 1</option>
       <option value="text2">Text 2</option>
        <option value="text3">Text 3</option>
</select>

 <ul class="searchandfilter">
       <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
 </ul>
```

EDIT : For IOS the select menu will be shown for a split second so instead you can add hidden class with css to prevent the list `<li>` shown at first so here is another way to do it:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select2").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".searchandfilter li").removeClass("hidden");
            } else{
                $(".searchandfilter li").addClass("hidden");
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

```css
.hidden {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select2">
       <option>Choose Text</option>
       <option value="text1">Text 1</option>
       <option value="text2">Text 2</option>
        <option value="text3">Text 3</option>
</select>

 <ul class="searchandfilter">
       <li class="hidden">Lorem Ipsum</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Amine KOUIS,, this seems to have worked!!  Is it only showing select2 once it's loaded on the system? ..... The reason I am waiting for select2 to laod, was to fix an issue with the IOS select menu showing for a split second, when I click on a dropdown mneu,,, unfortunately this hasn't fixed it....... Do you know a way of hiding or disabling the IOS select menu from showing?

Comment: Thanks @Amine KOUIS... I aupdated the code, I still see the IOS menu briefly [https://www.screencast.com/t/X1J4WSrfbox]